# Turn off all typings under a namespace for a particular file

Tags: typescript

I have a particular Typescript file in which I reference a particular namespace `MyNamespace`.  I'd like to turn off all typechecking for that namespace in only this file.  How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you could assign the namespace to a variable of type `any`?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to turn off all typechecking for that namespace in only this file. How can I do this

With a simple variable assignment. [Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20MyNamespace%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20safe%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20notSafe%3A%20any%20%3D%20MyNamespace%3B%0D%0AnotSafe.whatever%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error):

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    export const safe = 123;
}

const notSafe: any = MyNamespace;
notSafe.whatever; // no error
```

Comment: Hm, I get a "Cannot find namespace `notSafe`" when I try this.